# MATLAB function to find the last word in string

Tags: string, matlab, function

I'm looking for a code to find the last word in a string in the form lastWord(line) so for example,

```
line = 'hi how are you'
ans = 'you'

line = 'dog'
ans = 'dog'
```

I've gotten this code so far:

```
function finalword = lastWord(line)
    a = strfind(line, '');
    if ~strfind(line, '')
    finalword = line;
    return; 
    end
    lastSpacePlace = a(length(a));
    finalwordFirstIndex = lastSpacePlace + 1;
    finalword = line(finalwordFirstIndex:finalwordLastIndex); 
end
```

but i keep getting an error at lastSpacePlace = a(length(a)) and I'm not sure why. Any help is greatly appreciated!

edit: okay so I revised my code and ended up with this :
    function last = lastWord(line)
    allSpaces = findstr('', line);
    k = length(allSpaces);
    last=line(allSpace(k-1):allSpaces(k)-1);
    end

and i am STILL receiving an error in line(4) for some reason when I input any phrase. please I need some help on where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
line = 'hi how are you'
line(find(line==' ',1,'last')+1:end)
```

The last space is found and from that point to the end is the last word.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's unclear what the immediate problem with your code is since you haven't provided the entire error message for us. But one immediate issue is that you're never going to find spaces with `strfind` because you're using an empty string `''` rather than a space (`' '`).

That being said, I would just use [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) to split the input into a cell array of words and then return the last word.

```
parts = strsplit(line);
last_word = parts{end};
```

Another good option is to use regular expressions to grab the last word. The following expression matches all non-space characters that are at the end of the line.

```
last_word = regexp(line, '\<\w+$', 'match', 'once');
```

Comment: @henberry It doesn't look like you tried either of my suggestions. How about you try those